Как добавить метку для <Spinner />
В разметке есть spinner в приложении на нём есть метка с выбранным вариантом, но мне нужно сделать чтобы над выбранным вариантом была надпись к чему этот выбор, такой стиль можно встретить например в настройках где настройка выделена черным а ее описание серым.

Вы хотите чтобы Spinner был двухстрочный (и при выборе тоже)?

да, двух строчный, но так чтобы первая строка была статичным текстом а вторая показывала выбор)

Не понятно. Для "статичного текста" используйте TextView.

Извиняюсь, в mob недавно. Кнопка похожая на мое описание есть в параметрах разработчика телефона, если посмотреть там все кнопки с подписями и вот там белым или черным написано "Отладка по USB", а под этим серым написана подпись "Режим отладки"  и примерно такой результат мне нужен но если взять textview то службы доступности например talkback будут читать их как 2 разных элемегнта

Параметры разработчика - это список. Переключение там осуществляется через Switch (или в старых версиях через CheckBox). Если вам нужен такой результат используйте PreferenceActivity но она уже depricated.
